# what is the current use and future of icon programming language

Tags: icon-language

While studying different programming languages, I recently hit upon [Icon programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_(programming_language)). It seems to have quite cool syntax and functions for string scanning, goal directed execution, generators etc. and it was developed quite a few decades back (1977).

There doesn't seem to be much information available on it regarding the places it is used currently. It doesn't seem to be actively developed or supported also. I was wondering if people really use this language in certain niche areas even today or is the language now primarily of historical interest? Will it have much relevance in future also?

Comment: never heard of it, personally, before this question

Comment: While i was studying Modern Compiler Design I came to see a reference to the book "The implementation of Icon Programming Language" as the one of the few significant books which discuss implementation of an interpreter in depth. This is what intrigued me into looking up the language in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TIOBE programming language index http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html places it somewhere between 50th and 100th in terms of

> the number of skilled engineers world-wide, courses and third party vendors.

If it hasn't gotten any further than that since 1977, I doubt it ever will.

If you're into "cool," complex languages with sophisticated capabilities, [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) may scratch your itch.